# GridLayout columnSpan and rowSpan don't work properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

Here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="com.example.boowman.quickreminder.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar2">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:rowCount="2">

            <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="#dee2de"
                android:text="6th"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="#dee2de"
                android:text="6th"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="#dee2de"
                android:text="6th"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="#dee2de"
                android:text="6th"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="#dee2de"
                android:text="6th"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="#dee2de"
                android:text="6th"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="#dee2de"
                android:text="6th"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="#dee2de"
                android:text="6th"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="#dee2de"
                android:text="6th"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I try to set the rowSpan to 2 to any of the items nothing happens, columnSpan to 2 it works. Also setting both columnSpan to 2 and rowSpan to 2 won't affect the rowSpan.
Why this is not working and how I could make it work?

https://i.imgur.com/UESnCwS.png

In this screenshot you can see as soon as I put it rowSpan 2 (4th Item) the 3rd Item's rowSpan is canceled.
https://i.imgur.com/kN37tUU.png

Comment: Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: Updated the post.